# How to extract the vein pattern from an IR image of finger?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I am trying to isolate (or segment to be precise) the vein pattern from Infra red image of a finger (using MATLAB) like shown below:
[image]

So my output will be a binary image like (not the exact dimension of image shown):

[image]

I tried histogram equalization to make the veins more visible, but it was not that successful. Any help to proceed further would be very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to also try running a [ridge filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ridge_detection) on the dataset; something like [the frangi filter](http://fiji.sc/wiki/index.php/Frangi) might work.

A sample result is

[image]

*NB*
the white border is due to the border in the image I pulled from this site

Comment: Wonderful and thanks for the answer. Let me try this.

Comment: Another technique I saw just now : http://www.mathworks.in/matlabcentral/fileexchange/35716-miura-et-al-vein-extraction-methods

Comment: @dexterdev: Yeah I think they implemented a ridge filter that I mentioned - compare the first few lines of [`miura_max_curvature.m`](http://www.mathworks.in/matlabcentral/fileexchange/35716-miura-et-al-vein-extraction-methods/content/miura_max_curvature.m) with the equations on the [ridge detection wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ridge_detection)

Answer (score 1):

I tried using enhance contrast and histogram equalization on your image using [FIJI](http://fiji.sc/Fiji) and it seems to look pretty decent.[image]

You might still have some problems with segmenting due to the non-uniformity depending on the method you use.  If so perhaps look at local/adaptive threshold or something that looks for edges/maxima such as watershed based approaches.

Comment: I got similar image results previously. But cannot isolate the vein pattern, not able to produce the binary image as I have shown. I have used Otsu thresholding. Let me see other options.